Packages - not all files loaded
I want to use the package gptel.el (but this is only an example, the error also occurs with a few other packages) after the installation via Melpa (incl. init.el: require ‘gptel) I try to execute e.g. gptel-send (installation worked and some functions of gptel are available) and get the error: “Symbol's function definition is void: gptel-curl-get-response”. With find-function I see that the function gptel-curl-get-response from the file gptel-curl.el (c:/.../elpa/gptel/gptel.el, gptel-curl.el, ...) has not been loaded. If I load the file gptel-curl.el with M-x load-file the error disappears. c:/.../elpa/gptel is present in the load-path.
The error also occurs when I download the package directly with git clone and install it with M-x package-install-file.
Can you tell me where the error could come from and how I can make sure that all files of a package are loaded?
Many thanks for your help!
Info:
use-package.el
package.el
Windows 10
Emacs 29.3
gptel.241114

Show some code. Provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem, starting from emacs -Q (no init file).

@Drew Thank you very much for your reply!
Unfortunately, I cannot say where the problem lies with package.el, but I have now switched from package.el to straight.el, and so far all my packages, including gptel, seem to be working without any issues.

Sounds like the error occurs because you haven't loaded file gptel-curl.el, and apparently package gptel doesn't autoload function gptel-curl-get-response or some code is invoking it noninteractively.
You don't provide a step by step recipe to repro the problem, starting from emacs -Q (no init file), so it's not obvious just why it's not getting loaded.
Just put (require 'gptel-curl) in your init file.
